# Create iDevice HTML5 web app installation screen?

Tags: jquery, ios, html, web-applications

I have looked around all over stackoverflow and the internet for an answer to this one, and have found nothing unfortunately. OpenAppMkt has *just* an installation screen that allows it to install web apps for the iPhone, iPod Touch and iPad. When it is installed, then it shows *just* the app. Is there any way that I could replicate installation screen this for my current project? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it. On [apple meta tags documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html) there is a property called `window.navigator.standalone` that returns three values:

1. `true` if it is running as a web app **launched from the home screen**
2. `false` if it is running in a safari browser but **not as a web app**
3. `undefined` if it is running in any other browser (neither of the above)

This allows for detection as such that if it returns `undefined` then you can show something along the lines of "your platform does not support this web app", if `false` then you can show the "please install" and it `true` you can show the the running web app.

It may not be in the best interest of good UX to disallow the user to run the web app without installing it first, so perhaps prompting for installation but allowing use without it would be the best course of action.